# Merging cells in Excel by rows and columns together using PHPExcel

Tags: php, excel-2007, phpexcel

I need to merge cells in Excel (xlsx) by rows and again by columns using [`PHPExcel`](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/downloads/get/212184). I tried the following.

```
$sheet->mergeCells("G".($row_count+1).":G".($row_count+4));             
$sheet->mergeCells("H".($row_count+1).":H".($row_count+4));             
$sheet->mergeCells("I".($row_count+1).":I".($row_count+4));
```

Where the variable `$row_count` has some unpredictable dynamic value like 25, 50, 75 and so on (no regular pattern).

[image]

It merges the cells as shown in the preceding [snap shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQBjc.png) as can be seen immediately below the **Note** cell. After merging these cells by rows, I'm trying to merge them by columns as follows.

```
$sheet->mergeCells("G".($row_count+1).":I".($row_count+1));
```

but it doesn't work. When I try to open the excel file, it asks for a confirmation (with a confirmation box)

> Excel found unreadable content in 'report.xlsx'. Do you want to
>   recover the contents of this workbook? If you trust the source of this
>   workbook, click Yes.

How to merge cells by rows and columns together in Excel then?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Merging simply requires a valid range of cells like A1:B2, so your

```
$sheet->mergeCells("G".($row_count+1).":I".($row_count+1));
```

should work without any problem.

Can you please experiment with a simple test case to prove that this is causing you a problem, and not something else in your script

**EDIT**

After rereading your question:
Your problem may be that you're trying to merge cells that are already part of a merge range, rather than merging each row, then trying to merge by column, try merging the full rangein one go.

```
$sheet->mergeCells("G".($row_count+1).":I".($row_count+4));
```

Comment: @markBaker, I already used PHPExcel and I have only cumpliments to tell about this library. Now I'm working with Aspose for a java project and there's a limitation for this library that it seems PHPExcel also has.. We cannot merge already merged cells with a new one. Do you know why?

Comment: Mainly because it's painful to handle in the code, and adds an overhead for every merge, testing if it's part of any existing merge and amalgamating the two if it is... and which can't provide any feedback when it does so

Comment: This didn't work on me, im using maatwebsite v2.1.0.

Answer (score 11):

There is one more method for cell merging

```
    /**
 * Set merge on a cell range by using numeric cell coordinates
 *
 * @param   int $pColumn1   Numeric column coordinate of the first cell
 * @param   int $pRow1      Numeric row coordinate of the first cell
 * @param   int $pColumn2   Numeric column coordinate of the last cell
 * @param   int $pRow2      Numeric row coordinate of the last cell
 * @throws  Exception
 * @return PHPExcel_Worksheet
 */
     public function mergeCellsByColumnAndRow($pColumn1 = 0, $pRow1 = 1, $pColumn2 = 0, $pRow2 = 1)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
function cellsToMergeByColsRow($start = -1, $end = -1, $row = -1){
    $merge = 'A1:A1';
    if($start>=0 && $end>=0 && $row>=0){
        $start = PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex($start);
        $end = PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex($end);
        $merge = "$start{$row}:$end{$row}";
    }
    return $merge;
}
```

Addition to the case:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells(cellsToMergeByColsRow(0,2,3))
```

Answer (score 3):

I make a simple function to calc cells to merge by cols and row.

```
function cellsToMergeByColsRow($start = NULL, $end = NULL, $row = NULL){
    $merge = 'A1:A1';
    if($start && $end && $row){
        $start = PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex($start);
        $end = PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex($end);
        $merge = "$start{$row}:$end{$row}";

    }

    return $merge;
}
```

And call

```
$sheet->mergeCells(cellsToMergeByColsRow($col, $col+5, $row));
```

Thanks @Mark Baker

Comment: You might want to use the built-in helper functions PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString() and PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex() rather than your own chr/floor/etc because they're already built-in

Comment: Thanks to mention these helpers

Answer (score 1):

I was also looking solution for this question. where i want to merge cell and put content (value) on that. After few search i got some solution on this. but did not checked because i am using **Maatawebsite** for get **Excel** file.

But any one can try thing.. Solution is based on  **PHPExcel** nit sure ,it will work on **Maatawebsite**.

[Source Link](http://consistentcoder.com/merge-cells-in-phpexcel)

**Merge from column A row 1 to column E row 1**

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('A1:E1');

// add some text
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1','The quick brown fox.');
```

**Merge from column A row 1 to column E row 3**

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('A1:E3');

// add some text
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1','The quick brown fox.');
```

I checked maatawebsite document and they have same method **mergeCells**. so i think i would be work.

This Solution from Maatawebste.

```
$sheet->cells('A1:C1', function($cells) {
    $cells->setBorder('thin', 'thin', 'thin', 'thin');
});
$sheet->mergeCells('A1:C1');
```

Solution 2nd

```
$sheet->setMergeColumn(array(
'columns' => array('A','B','C','D'),
'rows' => array(
array(2,3),
array(5,11),
)
));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$sheet -> mergeCellsByColumnAndRow($col1, $row1, col2, row2);
```

is the function.